# Build configuratuin depended constants in UWP/C#

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to make a multiple branded UWP application. Everything wokrs fine, but I can't define my constants for builds. 
I have made build configurations for the brands and I added some pre build action they copies the assets and the other things, depends on the current build configuration.

How can I make this work:

```
#if brandAlpha
public string const MYCONST = "alpha";
#endif

#if brandBeta
public string const MYCONST = "beta";
#endif
```

It works when I use debug, but when I try to create a store package it says MYCONST is not exists...

I have made a screenshot:

[image]

This is how I would like to use it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is probably because neither the `brandAlpha` or `brandBeta` symbols were defined in your build configuration.

Assuming you're using Visual Studio, you should follow these steps :

1. Open the projects properties (double-click the property node in the solution explorer)
2. Click on the `Build` tab
3. Make sure the `Configuration` and `Platform` combo boxes have the values you're interested in.
4. In the field `Conditional compilation symbols` put either `brandAlpha` or `brandBeta`

Comment: @tixovoxi Are you sure you defined them for the correct configuration ? Would it be ok for you to add a little more details ? (a screenshot of the build page of the configuration that is not building and the code where you are using the symbols to define or not your constant)

Comment: @tixovoxi you can add the symbols for the all the possible combination of "Configuration" and "Platform" , just to cross check if you are missing any combination.

Comment: @tixovoxi From what I see the symbol is added for the x86 version of the application only, make sure the symbol is also defined for the other architectures